# MediaWiki sidebar reflow when page completes loading in IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, mediawiki

I've got a MediaWiki 1.23 setup, and I'm getting some odd behavior in IE.

In Firefox, when I load a page, the left navigation bar and site icon stays in the same place, and it appears like only the content changes.

However, in IE, occasionally when I open a new page, it's like IE hasn't quite loaded the site icon, so after the content appears, it shifts (or slides) to the right to make space for the icon.

Here's a gif of what I'm seeing:

[image]

I assumed that problem was something with my common.js/common.css or vector.js/vector.css.  However, I've reset these so that they're identical to Wikipedia's (I don't have this problem on Wikipedia), and I'm still getting this problem.

Comment: Do you have the same problem on Wikipedia if you say the config is similar?

Comment: A quick guess would be that your logo is too big, but I don't think that would affect the layout - it's a background-image after all.

Comment: I don't have the same problem on Wikipedia.  I'll update the question to clarify that.

Comment: I thought about the logo size, but it's exactly 135px x 135px, which is the specified size for Vector.

Comment: Ok, so I think I figured out why this is happening.  There's some JS somewhere that is changing the headers in the sidebar.  If I overload my computer enough, I can see the "Navigation" header (above Main Page and Recent Changes) pop in and out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug solved in 1.24](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki_1.24#Performance). We removed collapsibleNav, which as you noted was the source of the problem.